# Change title on Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a certain text on the table with a click of a button. In the table there's a header with the text a/d. With a click on a button I would want to have the user click on it to change the text a/d to say b/c.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#testTable").prepend("<div><button class='clickButton'>Click Me</button></div>"); 
$('.clickButton').on("click", function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
$("#testTable").find('table').find('tbody').find('tr:eq(0)').find('th').html().replace("a/d","b/c");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">This is a test
<br>This is a test
<br>(This is a test, a/d)
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Why would you want to prepend a DIV inside a TABLE?

Comment: Also, I see you asked already 8 questions without participating in comments and answers. Please take a [tour] to remind how this pages work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testTable").prepend("<div><button class='clickButton'>Click Me</button></div>");
  $('.clickButton').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // find the element you want
    var title = $('#testTable th')
    // get and modify the text
    var new_title = title.html().replace("a/d", "b/c")
    // replace old title with new text
    title.html(new_title)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">This is a test
        <br>This is a test
        <br>(This is a test, a/d)
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Not sure why you were using such wonky selectors.  Maybe this is just a watered down version of your code.  As it is, you just need to grab the only `th` inside of your table with an id of `testTable` (using `$('#testTable th')`).  In addition, you have to grab the text, modify it, then put it back where you want it.

Comment: Please modify your code with explanations to make it useful. (the wonky part :) `tr` with a `td` or `th` with `colspan` wouldn't take much time to edit and explain but would make your answer actually useful and correct)

Comment: So yeah,  you cannot (**should not**) append / prepend a DIV to TABLE.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're correct but that's outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

Modify the contents of your `click` function as below

```
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Find the element. Remember: This will return all the 'th' elements in '#testTable'
    var title = $("#testTable").find('th');

    // Replace string
    title.html(title.html().replace("a/d", "b/c"));
```

That should do it.